# Irreducible polynomial does not imply separable polynomial

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. I want to find an irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in F[X]$ such that is not separable. If $Char F = 0$, it is impossible to find (all the irreducible polynomial in a field of null characteristic are separable polynomials) and I have the next statement too:

> Let $F$ be a field and $f(X) \in F[X]$ an irreducible polynomial over $F$. Then $f(X)$ is a separable polynomial if and only if $f'(X) \neq 0$.

So, for instance, I have thought about a polynomial $f(X)$ in ${\mathbb{Z}}_2[X]$ such that $f'(X) = 0$ and it should work as a counterexample. For example $f(X) = X^2 + 1$, as $f'(X) = 2 X = 0$. It looks irreducible over ${\mathbb{Z}}_2[X]$, but how can I state that this polynomial is not separable? Which is the field of descomposition of $f(X)$ over $F$?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2$ won't work. All finite fields (and, as you have seen yourself, all characteristic 0 fields) are perfect, meaning that all irreducible polynomials over them have distinct roots. You need an imperfect field like in mathphys' hint, i.e. you need to consider polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[X]$.

Comment: How is ${\mathbb{F}}_p(t)[X]$ defined?

Comment: The coefficients of polynomials from $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[X]$ are rational functions (=fractions of polynomials) in the variable $t$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Can you define it as a set? I don't understand what you mean with ''in the variable $t$''. And I don't know what is ${\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p:=\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, you probably denote it as $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is kinda bad notation in algebra since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ also has another meaning. Then $\mathbb{F}_p(t) = \{P/Q: P,Q\in\mathbb{F}_p[t], Q\neq 0\}$. It is a little bit odd that you don't know the notation $\mathbb{F}_p$, but are asked about irreducibility and separability of polynomials.

Comment: is $t$ a variable like $X$?

Comment: $\mathbb F_p(t)$ is the quotient field of the polynomials in $t$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p$. $\mathbb F_p(t)[X]$ is polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i$ where the $a_i$ are elements of $\mathbb F_p(t)$. Don't worry about what $t$ is or isn't. Just think about it as an element of your ground field. $X^p-t$ is a perfectly sensible polynomial, and it can be checked that it is irreducible. But it is not separable.

Comment: Okay so ${\mathbb{F}}_p(t)$ is the minor field which contains both ${\mathbb{F}}_p$ and $t$, is not it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "minor field"

Comment: I am sorry. Is ${\mathbb{F}}_p(t)$ the smallest field which contains both ${\mathbb{F}}_p$ and $t$?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of thinking about it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: consider the field $\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ where $p$ is prime ($\Bbb{F}_p$ is a finite field) and $t$ is a variable.

---

Expanding on my hint earlier, $\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ is just the finite field of $p$ elements with $t$ a variable adjoined. You're probably familiar with something like $\Bbb{R}[x]$, the real numbers with a variable $x$ adjoined. This is the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in the real numbers. $\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ is similar, but here we are also allowed to "divide" by the variable $t$. So this is not only a ring, but a field too. For the formal definition, see July's comment.

---

Anyhow, consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^p - t \in \Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of this. Then consider $f(x) \in \Bbb{F}_p(t)(\alpha)[x]$. Since $\text{char}(\Bbb{F}_p(t)(\alpha)) = p$ prime, we have that $$f(x) = x^p - t = x^p - \alpha^p = (x-\alpha)^p.$$ It can be shown that $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p(t)[x]$, and so since $\alpha$ is a multiple root, we do not have separability.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ defined?

Comment: Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This is incorrect. $x^p - t^p$ is reducible in $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]$ -- it factors as $(x-t)^p$. I guess the polynomial you were looking for was $x^p-t$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.

Comment: Why do you deduce that char$({\mathbb{F}}_p(t)(\alpha)) = p$?

Comment: I don't understand the last step: $x^p - {\alpha}^p = {(x - \alpha)}^p$.

Comment: The characteristic is $p$ because $1 + \cdots + 1 = 0$ where we sum $1$ $p$ times. The fact that $\alpha$ and $t$ have been adjoined has no effect on this. The last step holds precisely because the field is of prime characteristic $p$.